# XPath for string contained in one XML element or another?

Tags: html, xpath, tags, web-scraping

I need an XPath that can find either an `<a>` tag, or an `<option>` tag, each one containing "something".

So the XPath would be able to match either

```
<a attributes='value'>something</a>
```

or

```
<option attributes="value">something</option>
```

I tried this:

```
$x("//*[local-name()='a' contains(.,'something') or local-name()='option' contains(.,'something')]")
```

I also tried this:

```
$x("//*[local-name(contains(.,'something'))='a' or local-name(contains(.,'something'))='option']")
```

But neither of them work. In the first one, I can exclude the `contains()` and it finds the tags, but I need to be able to search for those tags only containing the specified "something" text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should post your input XML.

Let's say it's this:

```
<r>
  <a>xxx something</a>
  <a>yyy nothing</a>
  <option>something xxx</option>
  <option>nothing xxx</option>
</r>
```

**(1)** Then (if you're trying to ignore namespaces):

```
//*[(local-name() = 'a' or local-name() = 'option')][contains(., 'something')]
```

**(2)** or (if there are no namespaces) [**credit**: earlier @alecxe post]:

```
//*[self::option or self::a][contains(., "something")]
```

**(3)** or (if using XPath 2.0, again without namespaces):

```
//(a|option)[contains(., 'something')]
```

will select

```
<a>xxx something</a>
<option>something xxx</option>
```